# Get device location periodically, even if app is killed

Tags: react-native, expo

I can't seem to find any supporting documentation in the Expo docs or React Native docs that say whether or not this is possible, so I figured I'd ask here.

I'm creating an app that needs to periodically fetch the device's location, whether the app is in the foreground, background, but *most important even if it's killed*. Even a few times an hour is fine.

Do both Android and iOS even support this behaviour? And if so, can someone point me in the right direction or provide the class/API that I would need to make use of in Expo/React Native (ideally in Expo) that would allow me to fetch the device's location periodically even if the app is killed?

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if React-Native has a "zombie mode" where you can schedule device queries (e.g. "location"), even after the app has been incapacitated or killed.

Comment: @paulsm4 Yes, pretty much

Comment: From a user point of view, if apple or android allow such a tracking feature, I will be more than just worried. 100% sure iOs doesn't allow this. not sure about android.

Comment: On iOS, I get notifications all the time about the Google Maps app using my location in the background, even when the app is dead. So I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, yes, it should be possible.

On Android, this is generally possible using a [Broadcast Reciever](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#receiving-broadcasts) (and see the information there regarding [getting user's location up from API 28](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts#android_9)).
On iOS, this is specifically possible using the [Standard Location Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW1) (specifically refer to the section "Getting Location Events in the Background").

Focusing on React Native, then again - focusing on Expo, there is a recent post discussing just that:
[The best way of tracking location in background using react-native + Expo in 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696365/the-best-way-of-tracking-location-in-background-using-react-native-expo-in-202). However, the [comments there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696365/the-best-way-of-tracking-location-in-background-using-react-native-expo-in-202#comment121109413_63269242) indicate that it doesn't work consistently.

Therefore, since I understand you don't specifically require using Expo (you just say *"ideally in Expo"* :), you can try following this React Native tutorial (June 2021): [React Native background location (background & terminated app)](https://jandemel.medium.com/react-native-background-location-background-terminated-app-6bedfb1f46e2) (it uses [`react-native-location`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-location) library).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this could be exactly what you're looking for:

React Native — Background Location Tracking without Timeout and with App killed

https://itnext.io/react-native-background-location-tracking-without-timeout-and-with-app-killed-3dbfbc80ad01